# How to intersect two Selects with Joins? SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with Artists and another with Prints. I want to get everything from the table Artist and just the print_id from the table Prints. Imagine if I have 3 Artists A, B and C. Imagine if artist A and B participated in print 1 and also 2. Artist C participated on print 2 and 3. What I want is the info about artist A and B because they participated on print 1 but also what other prints they participated (in this case, print 2).

Table Artist :
Artist A - Brazil.
Artist B - USA.
Artist C - Belgium.

Table Print:
1 - Wave.
2 - Map.
3 - Night.

Result Expected:
Artist A - Brazil - 1.
Artist A - Brazil - 2.
Artist B - USA - 1.
Artist B - USA - 2.

I'm trying like this but I'm getting some errors...

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM   
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
         artist.*
        ,print.print_id 
     FROM   
         artist 
         JOIN print ON artist.artist_id = print.artist_id 
     WHERE  
         print.print_id = 1 
     INTERSECT
     SELECT DISTINCT 
         artist.*
        ,print.print_id 
     FROM   
         artist JOIN print ON artist.artist_id = print.artist_id
    )
```

Comment: Which errors do you get?

Comment: Mysql does not support intersect, you have to use inner join instead.

Comment: Am I missing something or are these 2 queries the same except for the first being filtered on `print_id = 1`. If that is the case, then wouldn't the first query produce the result you want? I read it over a few times to make sure I am not missing something in your code, but let me know if I am.

Comment: I have a table with Artists and another with Prints. I want to get everything from the table Artist and just the print_id from the table Prints. Imagine if I have 3 Artists A, B and C. Imagine if artist A and B participated in print 1 and also 2. Artist C participated on print 2 and 3. What I want is the info about artist A and B because they participated on print 1 but also what other prints they participated (in this case, print 2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using join for the table (select) you have

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT
       Artist.*,
       Print.print_id 
   FROM Artist 
   JOIN Print
   ON Artist.artist_id = Print.artist_id 
   WHERE Print.print_id=1
   ) as T1 
JOIN
   (
   SELECT DISTINCT
       Artist.*,
       Print.print_id 
   FROM Artist 
   JOIN Print ON Artist.artist_id = Print.artist_id
   ) as T2 
   ON T1.artist_id = T2.artist_id
```

essentially the selects are  at tables  while a INTERSESCT corresponds to a INNER JOIN with the bond of union keys of the two tables/select

Comment: How is this different from what the first query (T1) returns?

Comment: I think this is a test query for ... test intersect .. (I don't know why th OP use this code... i simply try to solve a problem related to intersect in mysql)

Comment: Not sure you understand my comment. If you execute the first query in your code - you should get the same result as if you execute the entire query.

Comment: I get this error when i try the query :#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') on T1.artist_id = T2.artist_id

Comment: There was an open parenthesis that was not needed and causing the error. I just submitted the edit - it will show once/if peer-reviewed. You should try to debug these things on your own, though.

Comment: still doesn't solve my problem. No errors, but the results are not what I wanted

Comment: I have looked at your expected result but why you don't obtain result for C belgium and 3 night . I can not figure it out using the code you provided.

Answer (score 0):

The only sensible way I can understand the query is to assume that a `WHERE` clause is missing from the second subquery.

If you want to use `join` to check if an artist has two prints, then:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Artist a JOIN
     Print p1
     ON a.artist_id =  p1.artist_id AND p1.print_id = 1 JOIN
     Print p2
     ON a.artist_id =  p2.artist_id AND p2.print_id = 2;
```

I see no reason to select `print_id` in the `SELECT`, because the artist has both.